# how to draw a histogram using categorical varibles as y in R

Tags: r, histogram

I  have some data and wanna draw a histogram like this picture using R.

My data is:

```
 MCV   mortality
 100   0
 100   1
  90   1
  70   1
  70   0
```

I only want to show that mortality == 1 as proportion in y-axis.
I found some code but not exact what I need:

```
ggplot(data=t, aes(MCV, fill=mortality)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=c(..count..[..group..==1]/sum(..count..))),
                    
                 position='dodge', binwidth=5) +
  ylab("Percentage") +xlab("MCV")
```

Can someone give me some hints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you need exactly, but maybe this will do the job?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- t %>% 
  mutate(MCV_cut = cut(MCV, c(-Inf,70,80,90,100,Inf), c("<70", paste(c(70,80,90), c(80,90,100), sep = "-"), ">=100"), right = FALSE)) %>% 
  group_by(MCV_cut) %>% 
  summarise(mortality_perc = sum(mortality) / n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(dt) +
  geom_line(aes(x = MCV_cut, y = mortality_perc, group = NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this using `group = mortality`:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "MCV   mortality
 100   0
 100   1
  90   1
  70   1
  70   0", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(MCV, fill=factor(mortality), group = mortality)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=c(..count..[..group..==1]/sum(..count..))),
                 position='dodge', binwidth=5) +
  ylab("Percentage") + 
  xlab("MCV")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>